# Is it useful to upgrade "Cid, the Helpful Adventurer"?

Tags: clicker-heroes

In `Clicker Heroes`, there is a first hero, which is normally a hero for active players - `Cid, the Helpful Adventurer`.

I'm normally a passive player, which means I let the game run and just spent my money from time to time. But anyway, I just wanted to have an answer about the question, if it useful to upgrade `Cid`? Just expect that I would be an active player and I upgrade him. What is the benefit?

**All** heroes, except `Cid`, will gain a bonus after quite some levels (normally around 200+). This means, the heroes will get *4x* the `DPS` every 25 Level. Cid is still at a very low rate, even if he gets to Level 1000. Is there no bonus for him? Why should I upgrade him (besides the fact that I get 1000 or more Level which will give me a half hero soul.)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends on Active vs. Idle play style.

If you're Idle; 150 is as high as you need to go until you decide to ascend and pump levels into him to get hero souls.

If you're active; all your damage is going to be coming from him; so after you upgrade your heroes to the bare minimum to unlock skills; he'll be the only hero you upgrade (until you decide to ascend; and then pump levels into all the other heroes for HS)

Comment: Is leveling Cid actually more effective than leveling a hero that can be gilded for the +x% idle to click damage?

Comment: Does he really provide that much damage for active players? He is at Level 1225 in my current game and just produces 775M dmg? Will his damage increase in the kind as all the other heroes does (4x)? after some very high level?

Comment: I would think so.  If you're playing active; then your idle bonuses will be negligible.  Once you start pumping levels into Baahl, Fragsworth, and Juggernaut (and the other click skill ancients); Cid's damage gets multiplied; far outpacing anything you'd get from gilds.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer @JimB. Nice to provide you with additional 25 reputation. :-D

Comment: @Ionic Would like to add that Cid does not get any bonuses besides from either his own upgrades or the "0.5% of your DPS to click" upgrades.

Comment: With all respect, this answer is simply wrong. You need level 150 for the last upgrade. And upgrading Cid doesn't add any noticeable damage when you're past wave 75~.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid You're right; it is 150; not 125.  We'll have to disagree otherwise; as using an active build; your critical click damage will far outpace any DPS gained from heroes.  Especially with ancients involved.

Comment: @JimB Your answer doesn't mention critical click damage at all. Besides, it still doesn't matter when you upgrade Cid or not, the critical damage will stay more or less the same, because the base damage will stay the same.

Comment: I think it depends less on play style and more on how much you've progressed via ascensions. Carrying over a clickable gold drop item (eg goldfish) from level 1000+ through your ascension, allows you to easily skip to just about using only the power-ranger late game heroes. Also I can't believe I'm obsessed with a game simply about numerical progression. Not the first time, but still...

Comment: @Ionic the discussion in the comments here about the 4x/5x and 10x multipliers at 200, 225, etc to 1000 and through 4100 is misleading in regards to Cid. It's easy to see on the rollover when upgrading Cid that this hero never has such a multiplier. Because his ability is not about DPS and the multipliers are about DPS. Misleading may be too polite; one could say incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

It is useful to upgrade Cid to level 150, since that contains the last upgrade.
After that it doesn't do much damage since it is easily surpassed by it colleague heroes. You will notice that around wave 75~, maybe earlier.

If you want more click damage, simply get the 0.5% of DPS damage bonus for your clicks by upgrading the other heroes along the way. After that, keep upgrading the other heroes to get more DPS and therefore also more click damage. No matter what style you play!

When ascending, upgrade Cid to get a decent amount of upgrades so you can get another hero soul or two (1 per 2000 upgrades).

I tried upgrading Cid from level 200 to level 1100, but my click damage only increased with 1-2%, I was doing about 200O click damage at the time of upgrading. But that was probably mainly because of relics and ancients.

In my opinion, Cid is there to get you along the first 25 waves, especially when you play for the first time, after that it fades away in the shadows of the other hero's powers.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer is no.
Regardless of play style, Cid does not contribute to DPS, nor does Cid receive multiplier bonuses to any of his natural abilities at level 200-4100 which the others do (between 4x and 10x at 25 level increments). This makes leveling Cid mostly about unlocking his early boost to click damage. On about your 10th ascension and thereafter, you're unlikely to find even this click damage to be particularly useful; it would constitute less than 1% of the over all click damage from a roster of heroes generating DPS and a percent of DPS as click damage.

When playing idly it is important to note that you can totally skip any hero that is not either providing an important upgrade to:

- All heroes' DPS
- All gold collected
- Optionally, a skill you need (like the Dark Ritual, Energize and Reload)

Or who is significantly providing you with the most DPS.

Cid is never doing any of these. In effective idle play you can easily skip:

1. Cid
2. Treebeast
3. Ivan
4. Brittany
5. The Masked Samurai
6. The Great Forest Seer
7. Alexa
8. Natalia
9. Mercedes
10. Bobby
11. Sir George II
12. Referi Jerator
13. Ma Zhu
14. Athena

You could, as these skills are barely needed to make your optimal run time, skip:

1. Abaddon
2. Aphrodite

On the other hand, in active play, some of Cid's ability and upgrades could be useful (only) at the start. His ability gives click damage, his upgrades only affect himself. Thus, ultimately click damage comes from a factor of DPS via the abilities on Treebeast, Ivan, The Fisherman, Betty, Mercedes, Sir George II, and Frostleaf. See also those [heroes providing critical click upgrades](http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Upgrades).

If you're still at a level of play where ascending with 1-3 more souls makes any real difference to you, you will want to level Cid into the 2k, 4k, or 6k range. However if you really can hit the 6k range, you're probably at a level where ascending is giving you 80-90k souls. Those couple of souls from hero levels are negligible.

Always do an optimal run with a clickable left unclicked before ascending, and you can click it to carry enough coin with you to pay for a Shinatobe, Grant, Frostleaf, or greater. They will basically carry you to level 260+ by themselves.
**Note**: This likely has to do with my ancients, not simply the fact I carry a clickable through ascension. EG I have Dogcog:25. for half cost heroes, and Iris:175 for at starting level 176, which I think factors into the highest unlocked level that determines the value of the clickable, then I have Mammon:410 giving +2050% gold. I'm not sure that Libertas:395 factors in because the +6465% gold is "gained from monsters when idle" and clickables aren't monsters.
It's *well **worth** it* for me though as all that gives me a value of 1.019e35 for the clickable totally outweighing the 1e8 for having Kleptos:30.  This value allows me to right away buy:
Frostleaf:100, and 200 of everything below, plus all the available upgrade, activate metal detector and an energized dark ritual with reload... all of which will run close to optimally to level 265 (Again I do skip 2-175) before I have to or can buy any Dread Knight. 100 of those can run to about level 415 easily enough.

You can see my [screenshots](https://steamcommunity.com/id/4rky/screenshots) of an ascension:
[image: Clickable gold drop from lvl 1849 to lvl 1 via ascension nets 1.019e35 gold (10 1.019e34 valued coins as shown), from Iris:175 Mammon:410, Mimzee:415, Libertas:395 Khrysos:10.]

Comment: "Always do an optimal run with a clickable left unclicked before ascending, and you can click it to carry enough coin with you to pay for a Shinatobe, Grant, Frostleaf, or greater." - What does this mean? I've ascended once but wasn't aware of any way to carry coins across. What is a clickable in this context?

Comment: @Chris The clickable in this case is the one that occasionally pops up over the monster or on the right of the heroes list ui, which stays until clicked, and when clicked drops coins. In the current version it looks like a goldfish. It did not always look that way, which is why it's referred to as the "Clickable Treasure" instead of by it's current iteration: see http://clickerheroes.wikia.com/wiki/Clickables for the iterations.

Comment: Ah, cool. I'll be sure to remember that next time I ascend. :)

Comment: You last statement ain't true. I just tested it. I had a clickable, ascended and got about 4k gold... Instead of anything close to be able to afford a hero beyond Betty Clicker. I ascended at wave ~1200. You probably have Mammon on an insane level, or something like that.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I can't imagine you'd work to 1200 levels without maxing Dogcog, and getting a few hundred levels of Libertas (click when idle) and Mammon, a bit of Khrysos... I thought I qualified that as it works for me.

Comment: You don't get the point... When you click a clickable you will get the amount according to you CURRENT level, not the level the clickable appeared on. You'll need Mammon at least on level 100k+ to get some decent amount of gold for that. With Dogcog and Khrysos on max, you can buy almost 2 levels for Natalia. That's it. Nowhere close to Shinatobe. When testing this, I got Libertas and Mammon on level 300, Dogcog and Khrysos maxed out. Did you actually tested this yourself? Besides, you don't mention any ancient in your answer.

Comment: @dlamblin Why do you asume I did not invest in ancients? I just ascended to test it, because I had a clickable on that moment... Also, it happened that I never got the chance to select Dogcog or Mammon until the last 7 ancients, badluck I guess. It is very much plausible to reach level 1200 without Dogcog, Mammon and libertas, I'm not an idle player.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Oh you're not an idle player? How is that going… Idling has been a bit boring for me lately. I mentioned elsewhere that I used rubies from and during a weeks long run before hitting 15 real ascensions, which got me my main idling ancients. I have done 57 ascensions, the last 40 or so, each with carrying over a clickable that unlocks Frostleaf. It could be because I chose Iris and got it to over 150 that the clickable counts as valued from that unlocked level.

Comment: @dlamblin that last sentence in your comment is the key. I did not chose Iris (yet), so I start at level 1. Money gained is quickly increased in the first 100 levels. On the non-idle part, I use a nice macro to get me through the nights, but on the day part I'm either idle or click myself at strategic points (like bosses).